# MS SQL - Query takes too long to run

Tags: sql-server

I have a database trigger, than runs a stored procedure.

So this trigger runs,  every time a new data is inserted to the table.

here is the stored procedure query:

**EDITED: NEW QUERY**

```html
declare @transaction_type int
set @transaction_type = (select  TransTyp from inserted)


declare @transaction_ctr bigint
set @transaction_ctr = (select TransCtr from inserted)

declare @transaction_no nvarchar(15)
set @transaction_no = (select TransNum from inserted)

declare @transaction_date datetime
set @transaction_date = (select TransDt from inserted)

declare @customer_code nvarchar(10)
set @customer_code = (select CustCode from inserted)

declare @contact nvarchar(15)
set @contact = (select CellNum  from inserted)


declare @transaction_info nvarchar(130)
set @transaction_info = (select TransInfo from inserted)


declare @date_received datetime
set @date_received = (select DtRcv from inserted)

declare @is_active int
set @is_active= (select IsActive
     from BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentRegistration
     where CellNum = @contact)

declare @value nvarchar(130)
declare @pos int
declare @len int

if @is_active= 0 OR @is_active is null
begin
 delete from BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentTransaction where TransCtr = @transaction_ctr
end

else
begin
 --exec parseSentData @transType

 /** Inventory */
 if @transaction_type = 3
 begin
  if not exists(select TransCtr from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H where TransCtr = @transaction_ctr)
  begin
   insert into BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H
   Values(@transaction_ctr,@customer_code, @date_received, @contact)

   set @pos = 0
   set @len = 0
    while charindex('-', @transaction_info, @pos + 1) > 0
    begin
     set @len = charindex('|', @transaction_info, @pos + 1) - @pos
     set @value = substring(@transaction_info, @pos, @len)
      insert into BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_D(TransCtr, Material, Qty, ExpDt)
      select @transaction_ctr,
        ltrim(rtrim(left(@value, charindex('-', @value) - 1))) as Material,
        replace(substring(@value,charindex('-',@value),len(@value) - charindex('-', reverse(@value)) - charindex('-', @value) + 1),'-', '') as Qty,
        reverse(left(reverse(@value),charindex('-', reverse(@value)) - 1))as ExpDt
     set @pos = charindex('|', @transaction_info, @pos + @len) + 1
    end
  end  
 end
 
 /** Delivery */
 if @transaction_type = 2
 begin
  if not exists(select TransCtr from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H where TransCtr = @transaction_ctr)
  begin
   insert into BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_H
   Values(@transaction_ctr, @transaction_no, @transaction_date, @customer_code, @date_received, @contact)

   set @pos = 0
   set @len = 0
    while charindex('-', @transaction_info, @pos + 1) > 0
    begin
     set @len = charindex('|', @transaction_info, @pos + 1) - @pos
     set @value = substring(@transaction_info, @pos, @len)
      insert into BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Delivery_D(TransCtr, Material, Qty, ExpDt)
      select @transaction_ctr,
        ltrim(rtrim(left(@value, charindex('-', @value) - 1))) as Material,
        replace(substring(@value,charindex('-',@value),len(@value) - charindex('-', reverse(@value)) - charindex('-', @value) + 1),'-', '') as Qty,
        reverse(left(reverse(@value),charindex('-', reverse(@value)) - 1))as ExpDt
     set @pos = charindex('|', @transaction_info, @pos + @len) + 1
    end
  end  
 end

 /** ABIS */
 if @transaction_type = 1
 begin
  if not exists(select TransCtr from BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Abis_H where TransCtr = @transaction_ctr)
  begin
   insert into BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Abis_H
   Values(@transaction_ctr, @transaction_no, @customer_code, @date_received, @contact)

   set @pos = 0
   set @len = 0
    while charindex('-', @transaction_info, @pos + 1) > 0
    begin
     set @len = charindex('|', @transaction_info, @pos + 1) - @pos
     set @value = substring(@transaction_info, @pos, @len)
      insert into BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Abis_D(TransCtr, Material, Qty, ExpDt)
      select @transaction_ctr,
        ltrim(rtrim(left(@value, charindex('-', @value) - 1))) as Material,
        replace(substring(@value,charindex('-',@value),len(@value) - charindex('-', reverse(@value)) - charindex('-', @value) + 1),'-', '') as Qty,
        reverse(left(reverse(@value),charindex('-', reverse(@value)) - 1))as ExpDt
     set @pos = charindex('|', @transaction_info, @pos + @len) + 1
    end
  end  
 end

 /** end of transaction */
end
```

Let me tell you a story how it runs. The data is coming from an android app. It is an app for merchandisers in supermarkets. The app converts the data to SMS and sends the data to the SQL database.

Now, if the sent data from app is inserted to the database, the trigger fires, and the stored procedure above runs.

The stored procedure runs in this order:

1. Check the transaction type (in the above query it is 3 which is inventory)
2. Check all the record from **tbl_sentdata** that is not into **tbltransactionheader**, if not on **tbltransactionheader**, insert it there.
3. Check all the record from **tblsentdata** that is not into **tbltransactiondetail**, parse the delimited data, and insert each as one row.

**tblsentdata - data from  app**

**tbltransactionheader - header table**

**tbltransactiondetail - detail table**

Here is the raw data from the app:

[image: Raw Data]

Now, as you can see in the screenshot, the data from app is delimited. So I need to parse it one by one.(in the query above, the parsing starts from the comment "/* Loop delimited data */")

Now, if I run the stored procedure manually, for TransTyp 3(inventory), it takes too long.

In my guess, my query above, checks all the data from **tblsentdata** one by one.
so if I have 100, 000 records, it checks it every time even if the data is already on the transaction table.

Here are my questions:

1. Am I correct to assume this? If the trigger fires, the query runs. Then another text message is sent, the trigger runs again, even if the first query is not finished. Then another text message is sent, the trigger runs again.
2. Is my query above the best way to do this? Is there any way to this faster? I cannot afford to run this query it takes a lot of time.

Hope you can enlighten me I am new to SQL query. Or at least guide me where to look.

Hope I explained myself well. I would appreciate any help and suggestion. Thank You.

**UPDATE: 11/04/2018**

Thanks to **PSK**. With his help, I am able to resolve  my problem and minimize while loops in my query. I just removed the stored procedure. I run the query directly from the trigger and, just selected data from inserted.

**Please see the edited query above.**

Thankyou guys.

Comment: Please try to post a more minimal question, as your current one is very long.

Comment: You have a lot of queries running on BigEMerchandiser and BigESentData tables. Do you have index created on those tables for join columns?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, please forgive, I will try my best to minimize my question next time.

Comment: @Eralper, Hi!, the BigESentData has no index. But the BigEMerchandiser has the index but only the primary key. Yeah I have a lot of queries, in the example above, that is the only one transaction type. There are other transaction type. If the merchandiser sends transactions at the same time no wonder the server memory sometimes became full.

Comment: Hi, sorry I might right table names incorrectly. But as you mentioned, please give it a try with creating new indexes on those tables. Otherwise, your queries cause table scan, if those tables are huge, you have to read all data to find the rows you are looking. Also add additional indexes on columns used in WHERE criterias. Maybe you can also check missing index suggestion DMVs. Additionally you have row based code blocks instead of SET based operations. This is opposite to the fundamental approach of database programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using `WHILE` in your queries, it slows down you query badly. For your case, you can easily avoid the while loop, this will improve the performance of the query.

For example

**Existing code**

```
WHILE @headerCount > 0
BEGIN
    SET @transCtr = (SELECT TOP 1 TransCtr FROM BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentTransaction WHERE TransCtr NOT IN (SELECT TransCtr FROM BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H) and TransTyp = 3)

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TransCtr FROM BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H where TransCtr = @transCtr)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H
        SELECT TOP 1 TransCtr, CustCode, DtRcv, CellNum
        FROM BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentTransaction where TransCtr = @transCtr
    END
    SET @headerCount = @headerCount - 1
END
```

**Modified (without while)**

```
 INSERT INTO BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H
    SELECT TOP 1 TransCtr, CustCode, DtRcv, CellNum
    FROM BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentTransaction A

    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1 FROM 
        BigESentData.dbo.tbl_sentTransaction T WHERE TransCtr NOT IN 
            (SELECT TransCtr FROM BigEMerchandiser.dbo.tbl_Inventory_H) and TransTyp = 3)
        AND T.TransCtr = A.TransCtr
    )
```

Using similar approach you can implement for the second while loop.

Comment: Hi! I know that my query is reall bad, now I know why. Never knew that while is slow. Let me apply your suggestion and I will get back to you soon. Thank you so much!

Comment: hi PSK,  I have tried what you have suggested. It worksfine for the header. would you help me for the detail table? I cannot make apply your code to the detail? Thank you. I appreciate it.